# Elasticsearch ILM not rolling

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I have configured my ILM to rollover when the indice size be 20GB or after passing 30 days in the hot node

[image]

but my indice passed 20GB and still didn't pass to the cold node

[image]

and when I run: `GET _cat/indices?v` I get:

```
green  open   packetbeat-7.9.2-2020.10.22-000001                         RRAnRZrrRZiihscJ3bymig  10   1   63833049            0     44.1gb           22gb
```

Could you tell me how to solve that please !

Knowing that in my packetbeat file configuration, I have just changed the number of shards:

```
setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 10
  index.number_of_replicas: 1
```

when I run the command `GET packetbeat-7.9.2-2020.10.22-000001/_settings`  I get this output:

```
{
  "packetbeat-7.9.2-2020.10.22-000001" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "lifecycle" : {
          "name" : "packetbeat",
          "rollover_alias" : "packetbeat-7.9.2"
        },
        "routing" : {
          "allocation" : {
            "include" : {
              "_tier_preference" : "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "mapping" : {
          "total_fields" : {
            "limit" : "10000"
          }
        },
        "refresh_interval" : "5s",
        "number_of_shards" : "10",
        "provided_name" : "<packetbeat-7.9.2-{now/d}-000001>",
        "max_docvalue_fields_search" : "200",
        "query" : {
          "default_field" : [
            "message",
            "tags",
            "agent.ephemeral_id",
            "agent.id",
            "agent.name",
            "agent.type",
            "agent.version",
            "as.organization.name",
            "client.address",
            "client.as.organization.name",
```

and the output of the command `GET /packetbeat-7.9.2-2020.10.22-000001/_ilm/explain`  is :

```
{
  "indices" : {
    "packetbeat-7.9.2-2020.10.22-000001" : {
      "index" : "packetbeat-7.9.2-2020.10.22-000001",
      "managed" : true,
      "policy" : "packetbeat",
      "lifecycle_date_millis" : 1603359683835,
      "age" : "15.04d",
      "phase" : "hot",
      "phase_time_millis" : 1603359684332,
      "action" : "rollover",
      "action_time_millis" : 1603360173138,
      "step" : "check-rollover-ready",
      "step_time_millis" : 1603360173138,
      "phase_execution" : {
        "policy" : "packetbeat",
        "phase_definition" : {
          "min_age" : "0ms",
          "actions" : {
            "rollover" : {
              "max_size" : "50gb",
              "max_age" : "30d"
            }
          }
        },
        "version" : 1,
        "modified_date_in_millis" : 1603359683339
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's weird that it's 50GB !!

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show the settings of your index? `GET packetbeat-7.9.2-2020.10.22-000001/_settings` ?

Comment: when I run that command I get : 
```
{
  "packetbeat-7.9.2-2020.10.22-000001" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "lifecycle" : {
          "name" : "packetbeat",
          "rollover_alias" : "packetbeat-7.9.2"
        },
        "routing" : {
          "allocation" : {
            "include" : {
              "_tier_preference" : "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "mapping" : {
          "total_fields" : {
            "limit" : "10000"
          }
        },
        "refresh_interval" : "5s",
        "number_of_shards" : "10",
```

Comment: Sorry I Coudn't past all the output cause it's too long

Comment: Please update your question, as it's more legible

Comment: Also paste what you get from `GET /packetbeat-7.9.2-2020.10.22-000001/_ilm/explain`

Comment: I updated my question, and I think there is a problem as when I run `GET /packetbeat-7.9.2-2020.10.22-000001/_ilm/explain` it's showing max_size: 50GB !

Comment: Could you tell me please how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: As you can see, the max size for the rollover is 50gb (or 30 days) and not 20gb...

Comment: But as it's mentioned in the first pic, in kibana it's configured to be 20gb ! :(

Comment: Is it maybe because I edited it after that the index was created, so it will be 20gb only for the new index ?

Comment: Can you try to stop/start the ILM `POST /_ilm/stop` and then `POST /_ilm/start`. After that run explain again to see if it picked up the new definition.

Comment: unfortunately I got the same thing.. 50gb :(

Comment: It's weird because when editing a policy, the updated settings are immediately taken into account even for existing indices... Are you sure you saved your policy with 20gb?

Comment: yes, cause when I go to the policies on kibana and click on packetbeat, It's configured to be 20gb !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the solution of this problem.
After updating the policy, I removed the policy from the index using it, and then added it again to those index.